# lightning:container "Failed to load resource: too many HTTP redirects" in Safari, works fine in Chrome

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-container

I've a component which loads a html page from a static resource (which will have css & js files), the following is the code. It works fine in Chrome but doesn't load in Safari and throws an error:
"Failed to load resource: too many HTTP redirects"

.cmp

```
<div>
    Lightning Container
    <lightning:container src="{! $Resource.Container + '/index.html' }" onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}" onerror="{!c.handleError}" />
</div>
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Container</title>
</head>

<body>
  Container Body
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something to make it work in Safari also. Please suggest. Thanks.

Edit: I dont need React/Angular App, I'm simply looking for .html file in which I can use jQuery(/Froala).

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I am randomly having issues like this in both safari and chrome but it is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps to remove website data for Salesforce.com I was able to at least use lightning container in Safari,

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203370

However, I am not sure if/when the issue will reproduce again and suspect this will not be an acceptable work-around when it does.